# Problem package tutorial

Tags: ros, catkin-package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
after the creation of my beginner_tutorials package:

```
catkin_create_pkg beginner_tutorials std_msgs rospy roscpp
Created file beginner_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt
Created file beginner_tutorials/package.xml
Created folder beginner_tutorials/include/beginner_tutorials
Created folder beginner_tutorials/src
Successfully created files in /home/jacopo/catkin_ws/beginner_tutorials. Please adjust the values in package.xml.
```

if i use for example the rospack find, it say me this:

```
rospack find beginner_tutorials
[rospack] Error: stack/package beginner_tutorials not found
```

where is the problem??

Jacopo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195483/problem-package-tutorial/) by [JacoPisa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20532/jacopisa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2014-10-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) on 2014-10-21**:
Did you build your project with `catkin_make`?

If yes, have you sourced the workspace?

```
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

**EDIT:** fixed path

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2014-10-21**:
I believe Gary's command should actually have said `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`. Also, your `beginner_tutorials` package should be in `~/catkin_ws/src/`. It looks like you put it in the root of your workspace `~/catkin_ws/`.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2014-10-21**:
If your package is in the right spot, your `setup.bash` is properly sourced, and `catkin_make` built the package with no errors, and you are still having the issue, then you could try running the command `rospack profile`. That forces rebuilding of the cache that tells the system where packages are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

yes i made the catkin_make,
if i use:

```
source beginner_tutorials/devel/setup.bash
```

it give me this:

```
source beginner_tutorials/devel/setup.bash
bash: beginner_tutorials/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory
```

for create the package i've done exactly what the tutorial said, so:

```
mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src
cd ~/catkin_ws/
catkin_make
cd ~/catkin_ws/src
catkin_create_pkg beginner_tutorials std_msgs rospy roscpp
```

---

Originally posted by [JacoPisa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20532/jacopisa/) with karma: 110 on 2014-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) on 2014-10-21**:
can you try

```
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2014-10-21**:
Please don't create answers to provide more information. In the future, add this extra information as an edit to your original question. Otherwise, people think your question is answered when it's really not.

**Comment by [JacoPisa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20532/jacopisa/) on 2014-10-21**:
ok sorry for the wrong type of posting.

you are right, dont know why but my ros put the beginner_tutorials in the root and not in src.
now i've correct that and it works!

thank you guys and sorry for some mistakes

Jacopo